# tap gesture recognizer Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I want to make a 3d game on Xcode, SceneKit. To test it out, I started a simple project about a box, that if you tapped, moves in X direction. My question is how do you make the tap gesture work in a 3d game? I've been trying to add it but it just doesn't work. Here is all the code that I've written in case I'm doing something wrong:

```swift
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene(named:"art.scnassets/Box.scn")
        let newscene = self.view as! SCNView
        newscene.scene = scene
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(taps(tap:)));newscene.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    }
    
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    @objc func taps(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let newscene = self.view as! SCNView
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Box.scn")
        let box = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Box", recursively: true)
        let place = tap.location(in: newscene)
        let tapped = newscene.hitTest(place, options: [:])
        if tapped.count > 0{
            box?.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.moveBy(x: 5, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)))
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
@objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if(data.isNavigationOff == true) { return }         // No panel select if Add, Update, EndWave, or EndGame
        if(gameMenuTableView.isHidden == false) { return }  // No panel if game menu is showing
        
        let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: gameScene)
        
        if(data.isAirStrikeModeOn == true)
        {
            let projectedPoint = gameScene.projectPoint(SCNVector3(0, 0, 0))
            let scenePoint = gameScene.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(location.x, location.y, CGFloat(projectedPoint.z)))
            gameControl.airStrike(position: scenePoint)
        }
        else
        {
            let hitResults = gameScene.hitTest(location, options: hitTestOptions)
            for vHit in hitResults
            {
                if(vHit.node.name?.prefix(5) == "Panel")
                {
                    // May have selected an invalid panel or auto upgrade was on
                    if(gameControl.selectPanel(vPanel: vHit.node.name!) == false) { return }
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If Airstrike - Tap drops a bomb on the screen where you touched, translating it to 3D

Else hittest looks for panels which may return multiple results

Comment: In the code you put "gameControl" and "data". What do those mean?

Comment: Sorry, convenience paste.  GameControl is a custom renderLoop - start attackWave, loop thru game pieces, or whatever.  Data is just a class where I keep track of a number of vars.

Comment: thank you for answering me. I didn't exactly use your answer, but it led me to find a way to do it.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it.